# Encoding issue in QGIS while loading CSV file

Tags: qgis, encoding, arabic

I am trying to create a value map on a field by loading a CSV file that was Exported from Google Sheets, but QGIS is loading unrecognized characters. 
[image]

However, the Arabic characters do show up fine if I open up the CSV in notepad. As I understand, Google Sheets exports in UTF-8 which should be recognizable.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you set UTF-8 while importing the CSV?

Comment: I couldn't find an option to set the encoding in Google Sheets or when I load the CSV in QGIS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you import your CSV via `Layer --> Add layer --> Add delimited text layer`, you need to set the encoding of your CSV to UTF-8:

[image]

Comment: That worked, thank you so much.