# Accented characters in CSV file appear as '?' when importing to QGIS 3.34.2

Tags: qgis, shapefile, qgis-3, csv, encoding

I am trying to import a CSV set of data to join to a shapefile in QGIS but the accented characters and ñ character are displayed as missing in the attribute table and performing a join is impossible.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. The shapefile spec actually predates UTF-8 encoding, so all character set operations have been grafted on, and possibly inconsistently. There are ways to specify the character set of a dBase-III file. Have you done so?  Please [Edit] the question to include the list of file names associated with the shapefile set.

Comment: Probably your CSV file is not encoded in UTF8. Please have a look at the following question: [encoding issue with CSV in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/357298/encoding-issue-in-qgis-while-loading-csv-file), it explains how to specify the encoding of the CSV file when importing in QGIS